# Windows won't show FAT32 USB drive?

Tags: windows, usb, fat32

I'm hoping someone here can help me.  Recently, my Windows 8.1 has stopped showing any USB drive that's be formatted as FAT32 in This PC.

This seems to only be for FAT32 drives, because there does not seem to be any problem when I plug in a USB drive that's NTFS format.

Does anyone have any idea why this could be?  Could it be something in my registry?  Is there something I might have clicked on by mistake that could cause this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you check in Device Manager if your USB drive shows up at all? If it does, could you please also check Disk Management and see if there's an entry for your drive?

Comment: It is showing up in the Device Manager.  It is also there with Disk Management, however, it does not show that it has a format.  If that didn't make sense, here's a screenshot of Disk Management -- http://i.imgur.com/QRTFXvN.png

Comment: Wait, I'm sorry, I just made a mistake.  That particular USB drive was actually formatted as HFS+ (or OS X Journal).  I had grabbed the incorrect one.  Let me try with one that I'm just now going to reformat as FAT32.

Comment: That's strange.  Now FAT32 seems to be fine...  Sorry to trouble you!